# graph not rendering data points in extJS 6.5.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs6.5

In a line chart the data points surrounded by null points are not rendered.
For ex:

```
store: {
            fields: ['billperiod', 'charges', 'adjustments', 'receipts'],
            data: [{
                billperiod: 'January 2016',
                charges: 234243.33,
                adjustments: 3423434.12,
                receipts: 2342.22
            }, {
                billperiod: 'February 2016',
                charges: 234243.33,
                adjustments: 3423434.12,
                receipts: 2342.22
            }, {
                billperiod: 'March 2016',
                charges: 234243.33,
                receipts: 2342.22
            }, {
                billperiod: 'April 2016',
                charges: 234243.33,
                adjustments: 3423434.12,
                receipts: 2342.22
            }, {
                billperiod: 'May 2016',
                charges: 234243.33,
                receipts: 2342.22
            }]
        }
```

In above store the adjustments series misses a data point at billperiod: 'April 2016'. Anyway I can add a point there, I want the line to be discontinuous but a single data point added at that point. 
I have added a fiddler relating to the same.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/35ml&view/editor

Also I have attached the screenshots for expected and currently rendered graph from our production environment.

[Expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fJMP.png)

[Current rendered graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSTRl.png)

Comment: Any suggestions for this as I'm really struck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you use a line series to visualize the adjustments field. Because there are no values for 'March 2016' and 'May 2016' the graph can not draw a line ('April 2016' is only a single data point).

You could use the [scatter series](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.chart.series.Scatter.html) to add dots for every single data point. Either replacing the line series or just a new series with the same configuration:

```
type: 'scatter',
title: 'Adjustments',
xField: 'billperiod',
yField: ['adjustments']
```

Comment: So we can implement using this in normal scenario. But I was not able to do it using my config, so I just went with markers for these points. 
Thanks anyway.